# Questions regarding Manusmriti?

Tags: manu-smriti, smriti

There were some questions regarding Manusmriti, you are requested to kindly give the solution of our doubts.

1. [Chapter 4, verses 7 to 9] Why is the brahmin who keeps the food collection for a day, said to be the best?
2. [Chapter 4, verse 59] What is the reason for not showing the rainbow to anyone? Is there a story or scientific origin behind this?
3. [Chapter 7, Verse 168] According to Chanakya Niti, the order is - Sama, Dan, Dand, Bhed. But, from this verse it seems like - saam, daan, bhed, dand.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question has been drafted in Hindi & this is an English website.

Comment: Currently your Post contains multiple questions . Pls. Limit your query to single question at a time otherwise your post will likely to be closed.

Comment: The Sama Dhana Bheda Danada seems to be the proper order as far as I know, as punishment is the last form of control.